# FFMpeg series thumbnails created less than expected

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video

I have the following ffmpeg command to create a 576p video, and series thumbnails at an interval of every 2 seconds.

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i input_video.mp4 \
-vf "scale_npp=1024:576,hwdownload,format=nv12,setsar=1:1" -c:v h264_nvenc output_video.mp4 \
-vf "scale_cuda=160:90,hwdownload,format=nv12, select='not(mod(n,30))',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,setsar=1:1" output_thumbnails_%04d.jpg
```

The input video's frame rate is **15 fps**. Based on my understanding the filter `select='not(mod(n,30))',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB` should select frames that are not divisible by 30 (effectively extracting one frame every 30 frames).

Assuming the video is of duration 500 seconds, based on this logic I should get ~250 series thumbnails(one after every 2 seconds), but way less are created.

**EDIT:**

This sample media is 7min 32s (452 sec): [Sample media](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BiohMzjZKXXgTPIbPdoyuvvhzc2ZZN6O/view?usp=drive_link)

Only 166 series thumbnails are created whereas 226 should've been created. I can see the following warnings in the logs:

```
[NULL @ 000001FE8468DE20] missing picture in access unit with size 23
[h264 @ 000001FE8744E830] no frame!
[NULL @ 000001FE8468DE20] missing picture in access unit with size 8
[h264 @ 000001FE8744EBF0] no frame!
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
```

When I run similar command using `ProcessBuilder` in java, I get the process exit value as **69**. I couldn't find what that actually means in ffmpeg's context.

PS: When I replace the `select='not(mod(n,30))',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB` filter with `fps=0.5` I get the correct number of series thumbnails, but I can't use `fps=0.5` because it starts creating series thumbnails at around 1 second timestamp, whereas I want thumbnails from the very first frame i.e 0th second.

Comment: The issue is not reproducible. Please check using the following synthetic video: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=15:duration=500 -pix_fmt yuv420p input_video.mp4` (I am getting 250 JPEG images).

Comment: @Rotem I've updated the question with my sample media and further observations.

Comment: It looks like the video file is corrupted. Using the following command, I am getting 169 files: `ffmpeg -vsync 0 -i 1608313036729.mp4 -vf "select='not(mod(n\,30))',scale=160:90,setsar=1:1" output_thumbnails_%04d.jpg`

Comment: @Rotem Right the media seems to be corrupt. I just wanted to understand what's the possible cause that `select` filter creates less images but the `fps=0.5` creates the exact number of images.

Comment: I guess that `n` value of `select` filter counts only the frames decoded successfully, and `fps=0.5` checks if the timestamp difference from the previous frame is above 0.5 seconds.

Comment: @Rotem I see. Thanks. Can you please post this as the answer so I can mark it as Accepted.

Comment: @Rotem Also please have a look at my other recent ffmpeg related question: https://superuser.com/questions/1820293/ffmpeg-create-image-from-hardware-decoded-media-and-software-decoded-media

Comment: @Rotem Another please https://superuser.com/questions/1820325/ffmpeg-creates-image-from-a-timestamp-but-not-from-another-timestamp