# FFMpeg create image from hardware decoded media and software decoded media

Tags: ffmpeg, video, thumbnails

I'm trying to create an image thumbnail at a particular timestamp from a video.
While doing the activity I came up with two commands. Some videos were successfully processed by first command and some were processed by the second command.

Based on my understanding some videos were being hardware decoded and some videos were being software decoded by ffmpeg, hence I used `scale_cuda` and `hwdownload` to scale and download the frames from the GPU memory to main memory.

**For Hardware decodable media:**

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda -ss 00:00:10.0 -i "intput.mp4" -vf "scale_cuda=1024:576,hwdownload,format=nv12,setsar=1:1" -frames:v 1 output.jpg
```

**For Software decodable media:**

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda -ss 00:00:10.0 -i "input.mp4" -vf "scale=1024:576,format=nv12,setsar=1:1" -frames:v 1 output.jpg
```

Each video works with one of the above two commands and fails with the other. (Both the videos have same codecs h264 and are supported by my nvidia gpu for hardware decode)

My doubt here is why is some media HW decoded by ffmpeg and some media SW decoded. And how can I know which media is hardware decodable and which is software decodable beforehand.

Comment: It depends on your hardware's capabilities. Unfortunately, your question has no details on the hardware and no codec information for a video of either case (software/hardware decoded)

Comment: The cause is probably related to the **pixel format** of the encoded video. Example: encode YUV444 pixel format: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=15:duration=50 -pix_fmt yuv444p input.mp4` then decoding with `-hwaccel cuvid`, gives error message: `Hardware is lacking required capabilities` (in my machine). With YUV420: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=15:duration=50 -pix_fmt yuv420p input.mp4`, the hardware decoder is working. We may check the pixel format using [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) tool.