# FFMpeg creates image from a timestamp but not from another timestamp

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video, thumbnails

While trying to create an image from a video, the following command does not create any output and completes with the warning

**Command with timestamp 7 sec:**

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:7.0 -i "input.mp4" -vframes 1 -vf scale=1024:576,setsar=1:1 "output.jpg"
```

```
st: 0 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 0
st: 0 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 0.
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

But when i use timestamp as 14sec (total duration of video is 15sec), the image is created successfully with the following warning:

**Command with timestamp 14 sec:**

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:14.0 -i "input.mp4" -vframes 1 -vf scale=1024:576,setsar=1:1 "output.jpg"
```

```
st: 0 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 0
st: 0 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 0.
```

Input file to reproduce: [Sample Input file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R5oTiYuNyHdUXBAhS0jXs3m5RedyjkcC/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The issue is not reproducible... Try adding `-update 1` for avoiding the warning message. add `-y` for overwriting the file even if exist without asking: `ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:7.0 -i "input.mp4" -vframes 1 -vf scale=1024:576,setsar=1:1 -update 1 "output.jpg"`

Comment: @Rotem I'm okay with the warnings. The issue here is the output thumbnail is not created if I set the timestamp as `00:00:7.0` but it creates the output if the timestamp is `00:00:14.0`. Have attached the input media.

Comment: I am getting warning messages "1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp" and "Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 0" and "could not seek to position 7.000". When **remuxing** the file: `ffmpeg -i 925ca75a0895def832cb454985287731.mp4 -c copy my_copy.mp4` there is a warning "Non-monotonous DTS in output"... but `ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:7.0 -i "my_copy.mp4" -vframes 1 -vf scale=1024:576,setsar=1:1 -update 1 "output.jpg"` is working. I guess there is an issue with the MP4 file container.

Comment: @Rotem I'm wondering if there's way to extract the image at the nearest timestamp (after 7 seconds) where it is possible.

Comment: Isn't it working after remuxing?

Comment: @Rotem Unfortunately I do not have the luxury to use multiple commands instead of 1. It works if I use `-ss` param after the input file in my command but it takes way longer to execute for larger videos which I can't afford. I was looking for a possible solution if the same command of mine can be modified to to extract the image at the nearest keyframe after 7 sec.

Comment: @Rotem I've also tried using the filter `select="eq(pict_type\,I)"` but no luck.